# How to determine the size of a subset of rows in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, select, memory, hard-drive

How can I calculate the size in Bytes (MB, GB) used by a subset of rows in a MySQL table.
The use case is to determine the footprint of a user in the database. So the idea is to select all rows that belong to a user in a table a calculate the size of those rows including their indices (indexes?)

I found something like this, but this only gives me the size of the whole table:

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

I would really appreciate an answer to that.

Comment: Note that anything divided by itself is 1. Is that the problem?

Comment: @Strawberry The calc will work left to right so this is `(sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024)/1024`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to get an estimate. I assume that you can count the number of rows in the table 'owned' by that user, and from that and the total number of rows you can get the percentage of rows 'owned' by that user. Apply that percentage to the total size of the table and you have your estimate.

If you try for anything more accurate you are unlikely to achieve it without a lot of hard work, and it will probably involve making estimate about other things, so I'd say just go with the estimate. If I was asked to do this, I'd say that it wouldn't be possible to be accurate but that a reasonable estimate could be made, is that good enough....

Comment: Thank you. What about indices? Is it save to assume the index grows linearly?

Comment: Not really; it depends in the pattern of adding keys. If the key is always increasing (e.g. an int which increases by 1 each time) then you can probably assume that. If it's not (e.g. a random Guid) then probably not as adding any key can cause a page split. What are you actually trying to achieve here? DForward planning for space requirements, or something else?

Comment: Exactly that. We try to estimate the space requirements for an upcoming rollout. We have multiple indices per table. Some of them are based on an auto-increment id, others a composite indexes.

Comment: OK. I'm going to take back what I said about Indexes. In these circumstances assuming a linear growth is OK for both index and data - it will give you a good estimate provided that you accept that it is an estimate. The problem here is usage patterns: are there going to be the same mix of additions to tables in production as there has been in dev/test. As a silly example take Facebook: if in test the average user has x friends but in prod they have 2x or .5x then your estimate will be off. You need good estimates of this sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, of course. We take a model user for our estimates, realizing that this can always be just an average. Thank you for all your valuable input.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the rollout!